# How to read a specific part of a text file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

I want to read a text file line by line with nodejs. 
This works fine with a readable stream. 
The problem is a other program adds lines to the file. I just want to read the new lines or changes and not the hole file. 
I Tried it with the functions to move the cursor. But this works only with a writable stream. 
Is there a possibility to resume the stream after the 'end' event occurs? Or how I can read just a few lines at a specific position of a File?

```
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
var data = '';

readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data+=chunk;
});

readableStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It work also fine with the [readline](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) core module. 
But how I can read a single line from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way of doing this would be to save the last position and skip those bytes on the next read with [stream-skip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-skip)

Answer (score 2):

The filestream library has a `watch` function which you can use to watch changes in a file. The function executes when there are changes in the file either from nodejs or from external source.

```
fs.watch('pathToDirectory', function (event, filename) {
    console.log('event is: ' + event);
    if (filename) {
        console.log('filename provided: ' + filename);
    } else {
        console.log('filename not provided');
    }
});
```

You can read further [fs.watch()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) to know more about this. This is what you should use to achieve what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already use this function. The Problem is the file can change very frequently and getting bigger. When I read the total file every time after it changes its getting real inefficient. Or is there a possibility to get the changes?